# Html links with google Inbox app

Tags: android, gmail, google-inbox

trying to create an email intent which contains a few links with text

```
    String emailText = "Hey, click me <a href=\"https://www.google.com\">This is a google link</a>";

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

    emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    emailIntent.setType("*/*");
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailText));
```

If i open the intent with the **GMAIL** app, it will display the html contents correctly. But if i open it the google **Inbox** app the html parts are ignored.

Any ideas how to display html in all email clients?

Comment: Maybe it could be an character encoding problem...

Comment: You could try with `emailText = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(emailText)`, using this [library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2): add compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2' in your build.gradle and let me know!

Comment: When you say that html parts are ignored do you mean that Inbox does an html unwrapping or simply that doesn't show the text "This is a google link"?

Comment: @madx I tried this method but it displayed the html tags as plain text. When i say that the html tags are ignored, i mean that it displays just the "This is a google link" without any html tags(not even plain text)

Comment: Found any solution ?